# NECESITO CONSEJOS

Tags: c

yo estoy programando el siguiente ejercicio y me esta costando un poco,
Este es el ejercicio

> En un colegio se le toma para ser ingresantes tres exámenes para el
> ingreso en las materias matemática, física y química. Se ingresan las
> notas de cada una de las pruebas de los aspirantes, el último
> aspirante tiene 0 en las tres notas.
>
> Se debe desarrollar un programa que utilice funciones y que me
> permita:
>
> a)      si el promedio de las tres notas es superior o igual a 6 deber
> mostrar un mensaje “Admitido”, en caso contrario “Debe recuperar”.
>
> b)      La cantidad de alumnos cuyas notas sean mayores o iguales a 8.
>
> c)      Mostrar las notas ingresadas del i-enesimo lugar, donde i debe
> ser ingresado previamente y por única vez.
>
> d)      El porcentaje de admitidos sobre el total ingresado.
>
> e)      A cada alumno se lo debe ubicar en una de las 10 divisiones
> que tiene el colegio. La particularidad de estas es que son números
> romanos. Las divisiones son I,II,III, IV…IX y X. Se debe informar a
> que división corresponde cada alumno que será la primera nota
> ingresada de la terna convertida en número romano.

Esto es lo que yo hice:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int nota;
float Promedio;

int main(){
    
    
    printf("nota1: "); 
    scanf("%d",&nota);
    printf("nota2: ");
    scanf("%d",&nota);
    printf("nota3: ");
    scanf("%d",&nota);
    
    if(Promedio >= 6){
        puts("Admitido");
    }
    else{
            puts("Debe recuperar");
        }
    
    return 0;
    }
```

Pero me estaría costando seguirlo. Alguien sabe qué más agregarle?

Comment: Por qué las etiquetas de java y javascript ?

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], edita y redacta un título objetivo referente al problema expuesto

Comment: Falta una estructura de datos en la que lleves el registro de cada estudiante con sus notas. Falta calcular el promedio antes de compararlo con 6. Falta llevar el conteo de cuántos tienen promedio mayor a 8, falta calcular el porcentaje. Falta revisar en qué lenguaje lo vas a hacer, porque hablas de java y javascript pero tu código es C. Las etiquetas no son hashtags de instagram ;)

Comment: ¿Cuál es la duda?

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822